# Markercluster spiderfy - Nearby coordinates are displayed in single spiderfy instead of separate marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have used 'Leaflet.markercluster' plugin with leaflet library to display the cluster & spiderfy in my map.

But when applying the latitude & longitude coordinates in marker, if the coordinates are nearby / very close, then both coordinates are displayed in a single spiderfy view.

Actually, I wanted to display those coordinates as a separate marker.

In Example, You can see in 'markers' array, I have used the first two object with identical coordinates and the third one differs from the first two. But all three marker display in single spiderfy. Actually, I wanted first two as spiderfy and third one as a separate marker.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Leaflet Cluster Example</h1>

  <p>Here's an interactive map indicating where airports and train stations are located around the world. The data comes from <a href="http://openflights.org/data.html" target="_blank">OpenFlights.org</a>.

    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var markers = [{
        "name": "Goroka",
        "city": "Goroka, Papua New Guinea",
        "iata_faa": "GKA",
        "icao": "AYGA",
        "lat": 38.98856,
        "lng": -77.32219,
        "alt": 5282,
        "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
      }, {
        "name": "Madang",
        "city": "Madang, Papua New Guinea",
        "iata_faa": "MAG",
        "icao": "AYMD",
        "lat": 38.98856,
        "lng": -77.32219,
        "alt": 20,
        "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
      }, {
        "name": "Mount Hagen",
        "city": "Mount Hagen, Papua New Guinea",
        "iata_faa": "HGU",
        "icao": "AYMH",
        "lat": 38.98852,
        "lng": -77.32183,
        "alt": 5388,
        "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
      }];

      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [10.0, 5.0],
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoom: 2
      });

      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
      }).addTo(map);

      var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/images/marker-icon.png',
        iconSize: [29, 24],
        iconAnchor: [9, 21],
        popupAnchor: [0, -14]
      });

      var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
        var popup = markers[i].name +
          '<br/>' + markers[i].city +
          '<br/><b>IATA/FAA:</b> ' + markers[i].iata_faa +
          '<br/><b>ICAO:</b> ' + markers[i].icao +
          '<br/><b>Altitude:</b> ' + Math.round(markers[i].alt * 0.3048) + ' m' +
          '<br/><b>Timezone:</b> ' + markers[i].tz;

        var m = L.marker([markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {
            draggable: true,
            icon: myIcon
          })
          .bindPopup(popup);

        markerClusters.addLayer(m);

      }

      markerClusters.on("clusterclick", function(c) {
        var cluster = c.layer,
          bottomCluster = cluster;

        while (bottomCluster._childClusters.length === 1) {
          bottomCluster = bottomCluster._childClusters[0];
        }

        if (bottomCluster._zoom === markerClusters._maxZoom &&
          bottomCluster._childCount === cluster._childCount) {

          c.layer.zoomToBounds();
        }

      });

      map.addLayer(markerClusters);
    </script>
</body>
```

Please how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) by default clusters Markers which are closer than 80 pixels (see option [`maxClusterRadius`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-options)).

Therefore if at maximum map zoom, your 3 Markers are still within 80 pixels from each other, the plugin will put them in the same cluster, and spiderfy all 3 of them together.

Now if you do not want those Markers clustering at maximum zoom unless they are exactly at the same position, you would be interested in [Leaflet.markercluster #339](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/339):

> [...] it seems to me that in fact you want "no clustering" at zoom level 15 and higher, EXCEPT for markers which are at the VERY SAME position (lat/lng).
>
> You could approach this functionality by using a `maxClusterRadius` function that returns normal radius (default 80 pixels) for zoom levels 0 to 14, and 1 pixel for level 15 and beyond:

```js
var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup({
    maxClusterRadius: function (zoom) {
        return (zoom <= 14) ? 80 : 1; // radius in pixels
    }
});
```

> With this, for zoom level 15 and higher, the plugin will still cluster markers that are within 1 pixel from each other. If I recall correctly, using 0 pixel does not work unfortunately. But 1 pixel distance is already very small, as if the markers were at the very same position.

Example:

```js
var markers = [{
  "name": "Goroka",
  "city": "Goroka, Papua New Guinea",
  "iata_faa": "GKA",
  "icao": "AYGA",
  "lat": 38.98856,
  "lng": -77.32219,
  "alt": 5282,
  "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
}, {
  "name": "Madang",
  "city": "Madang, Papua New Guinea",
  "iata_faa": "MAG",
  "icao": "AYMD",
  "lat": 38.98856,
  "lng": -77.32219,
  "alt": 20,
  "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
}, {
  "name": "Mount Hagen",
  "city": "Mount Hagen, Papua New Guinea",
  "iata_faa": "HGU",
  "icao": "AYMH",
  "lat": 38.98852,
  "lng": -77.32183,
  "alt": 5388,
  "tz": "Pacific/Port_Moresby"
}];

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [38, -77],
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 18,
  zoom: 2
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup({
  // From https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/339
  maxClusterRadius: function(zoom) {
    return (zoom <= 14) ? 80 : 1; // radius in pixels
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
  var popup = markers[i].name +
    '<br/>' + markers[i].city +
    '<br/><b>IATA/FAA:</b> ' + markers[i].iata_faa +
    '<br/><b>ICAO:</b> ' + markers[i].icao +
    '<br/><b>Altitude:</b> ' + Math.round(markers[i].alt * 0.3048) + ' m' +
    '<br/><b>Timezone:</b> ' + markers[i].tz;

  var m = L.marker([markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng])
    .bindPopup(popup);

  markerClusters.addLayer(m);

}

map.addLayer(markerClusters);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: **@ghybs:** Thanks to updated the question and detailed explanation. Thanks a lot, works now!.
Actually, I wanted the clustering at max zoom level too. But I didn't want that nearby coordinates are displayed in single spiderfy.

I need one more help which related to this. I have posted the question. So [please check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557028/markercluster-spiderfy-map-max-zoom-level-displays-the-marker-icon-groups-inst). Help me to resolve this too!